# bootstrap validator reset form not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am trying to reset the form using bootstrap validator

When i click on reset, its removing the input values, but when i click submit even when the input is empty, its still submitting, when it should be showing an error

Here is the js

```
    $('#shortener').bootstrapValidator({
        container: '#sstatus',
        fields: {
            url: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Enter a url!'
                    },
                    uri: {
                        message: 'URL is not a valid url, include http://'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('in');

            // Get the form instance
            var $form = $(e.target);

            // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
            var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            $.post('ajax/new_url.php', $form.serialize(), function(result) {

                console.log('works'+result.message);

                $('#shortener').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $form.bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true); 
                });

                $(document).on('click', '#shorten_again', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

            }, 'json');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

$('form').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);

Answer (score -1):

You need to address methods when submitting, clearing and resetting:

```
    .on('init.field.bv', function(e, data) {
        // data.bv      --> The BootstrapValidator instance
        // data.field   --> The field name
        // data.element --> The field element

        var $parent = data.element.parents('.form-group'),
            $icon   = $parent.find('.form-control-feedback[data-bv-icon-for="' + data.field + '"]');

        // From v0.5.3, you can retrieve the icon element by
        // $icon = data.element.data('bv.icon');

        $icon.on('click.clearing', function() {
            // Check if the field is valid or not via the icon class
            if ($icon.hasClass('glyphicon-remove')) {
                // Clear the field
                data.bv.resetField(data.element);
            }
        });
    })
```

Reference: [BootstrapValidator Clearing Field Example](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/clearing-field-when-clicking-icon/)